# Full duplex communication between wcf applications

Tags: c#, wcf

For a proof of concept, I am trying to write two applications WcfApp1 and WcfApp2.

**Problem:**
I am able to add service reference of WcfApp1 in WcfApp2 solution, but unable to add WcfApp2 in WcfApp1. Although the code is same (of course changing basic_httpbinding_url).
Can anyone tell me what could be wrong with this?

**Detail:**

WcfApp1 has:

IWcfApp1_Class -> interface;

WcfApp1_Class -> class derived from interface above;

WcfApp1_DClass -> class (as data structure);

WcfApp2 has:

IWcfApp2_Class -> interface;

WcfApp2_Class -> class derived from interface above;

WcfApp2_DClass -> class (as data structure);

**Code of WcfApp1:**

```
Uri baseAddress_BasicHttpBinding = new Uri("http://localhost:9001/WcfApp1");
Uri baseAddress_NetTcpBinding = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9001/WcfApp1");
Uri baseAddress_NetNamedPipeBinding = new Uri("http://localhost:9001/WcfApp1");// new Uri("net.pipe://localhost:9001/WcfApp1");
Uri baseAddress_WSHttpBinding = new Uri("http://localhost:9001/WcfApp1");
Uri baseAddress_WSDualHttpBinding = new Uri("http://localhost:9001/WcfApp1");

ServiceHost host;

public void f_BasicHttpBinding()
{

    host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfApp1_Class), baseAddress_BasicHttpBinding);
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

    var behavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
    behavior.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;

    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

    try
    {
        host.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception exxx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exxx.ToString());
    }
}
```

**IWcfApp1_Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace WcfApp1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IWcfApp1_Class
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Function1();

        [OperationContract]
        int Function2();

        [OperationContract]
        string Function3();

        [OperationContract]
        WcfApp1_DClass Function4();

        [OperationContract]
        void Function5(WcfApp1_DClass data);

        [OperationContract]
        WcfApp1_DClass Function6(WcfApp1_DClass data);
    }

}
```

**WcfApp1_Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WcfApp1
{
    class WcfApp1_Class :
        IWcfApp1_Class
    {
        public void Function1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Function1 executed...");
        }

        public int Function2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Function2 executed...");
            return 1;
        }

        public string Function3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Function3 executed...");
            return "WcfApp1_Class->Function3";
        }

        public WcfApp1_DClass Function4()
        {
            WcfApp1_DClass data = new WcfApp1_DClass
            {
                student_Id = 1,
                student_Name = "WcfApp1_DClass"
            };
            Console.WriteLine("Function4 executed...");
            return data;
        }

        public void Function5(WcfApp1_DClass data)
        {
            if(data.student_Id == 2 && data.student_Name == "WcfApp2_DClass")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Function5 executed... OK...");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Function5 executed... NOT OK...");
            return;
        }

        public WcfApp1_DClass Function6(WcfApp1_DClass data)
        {
            if (data.student_Id == 2 && data.student_Name == "WcfApp2_DClass")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Function6 executed... OK...");
                data.student_Name = "WcfApp1_DClass";
                return data;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Function6 executed... NOT OK...");
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

**WcfApp1_DClass:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace WcfApp1
{
    [DataContract]
    class WcfApp1_DClass
    {
        private int _student_Id;
        private string _student_Name;

        [DataMember]
        public int student_Id
        {
            get
            {
                return _student_Id;
            }
            set
            {
                if(_student_Id != value)
                {
                    _student_Id = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string student_Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _student_Name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_student_Name != value)
                {
                    _student_Name = value;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Code of WcfApp2:**

```
Uri baseAddress_BasicHttpBinding = new Uri("http://localhost:9002/WcfApp2");
        Uri baseAddress_NetTcpBinding = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9002/WcfApp2");
        Uri baseAddress_NetNamedPipeBinding = new Uri("http://localhost:9002/WcfApp2");// new Uri("net.pipe://localhost:9002/WcfApp2");
        Uri baseAddress_WSHttpBinding = new Uri("http://localhost:9002/WcfApp2");
        Uri baseAddress_WSDualHttpBinding = new Uri("http://localhost:9002/WcfApp2");

        ServiceHost host;

        public void f_BasicHttpBinding()
        {

            host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfApp2_Class), baseAddress_BasicHttpBinding);
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

            var behavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
            behavior.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;

            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            try
            {
                host.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception exxx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exxx.ToString());
            }
        }
```

**IWcfApp2_Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace WcfApp2
{
    interface IWcfApp2_Class
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Function1();

        [OperationContract]
        int Function2();

        [OperationContract]
        string Function3();

        [OperationContract]
        WcfApp2_DClass Function4();

        [OperationContract]
        void Function5(WcfApp2_DClass data);

        [OperationContract]
        WcfApp2_DClass Function6(WcfApp2_DClass data);
    }
}
```

**WcfApp2_Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WcfApp2
{
    class WcfApp2_Class :
        IWcfApp2_Class
    {
        public void Function1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Function1 executed...");
        }

        public int Function2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Function2 executed...");
            return 1;
        }

        public string Function3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Function3 executed...");
            return "WcfApp1_Class->Function3";
        }

        public WcfApp2_DClass Function4()
        {
            WcfApp2_DClass data = new WcfApp2_DClass
            {
                student_Id = 1,
                student_Name = "WcfApp1_DClass"
            };
            Console.WriteLine("Function4 executed...");
            return data;
        }

        public void Function5(WcfApp2_DClass data)
        {
            if (data.student_Id == 2 && data.student_Name == "WcfApp2_DClass")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Function5 executed... OK...");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Function5 executed... NOT OK...");
            return;
        }

        public WcfApp2_DClass Function6(WcfApp2_DClass data)
        {
            if (data.student_Id == 2 && data.student_Name == "WcfApp1_DClass")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Function6 executed... OK...");
                data.student_Name = "WcfApp2_DClass";
                return data;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Function6 executed... NOT OK...");
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

**WcfApp2_DClass:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace WcfApp2
{
    [DataContract]
    class WcfApp2_DClass
    {
        private int _student_Id;
        private string _student_Name;

        [DataMember]
        public int student_Id
        {
            get
            {
                return _student_Id;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_student_Id != value)
                {
                    _student_Id = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string student_Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _student_Name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_student_Name != value)
                {
                    _student_Name = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Message:**

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://localhost:9002/WcfApp2/$metadata'. The request failed with
>   HTTP status 405: Method Not Allowed. Metadata contains a reference
>   that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:9002/WcfApp2'. There was no
>   endpoint listening at http://localhost:9002/WcfApp2 that could accept
>   the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP
>   action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. The remote
>   server returned an error: (404) Not Found. If the service is defined
>   in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the
>   service reference again.

[image]

Comment: When exactly do you get the error message?

Comment: When I try to add service reference using Visual Studio.

Comment: Was WcfApp2 running while you tried that?

Comment: Yes, the application was running.. Browser page also appears...

Comment: Okay, found the error, I will add it to answer. I was missing [ServiceContract] in the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the trouble spot.

I was missing `[ServiceContract]` in `IWcfApp2_Class` interface.